# Not able to validate the string via regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate the string `{233}{232}{112}{3232}` with regex in java. I am using `Pattern.compile("\\{([^\\}]*.?)\\}")` but I'm not able to validate this string.

Here in the string, multiple ids are divided by the curly braces and the ID must be numeric.

Some test cases:

Test case 1: `{122}{323}  //true`

Test case 2: `{122}323}  //false`

Test case 3: `{122323}  //true`

Test case 4: `{122},{323}  //false`

Test case 5: `{xx}{YY}  //false`

Can anyone help me on this? Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Pattern.compile("(\\{([^{}]*.?)\\})*") perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is off, you should be using this:

```
(?:\{\\d*\})+
```

You seem to have some confusion about how to tell the regex engine to capture everything up until the *first* closing bracket.  One could use `[^}]*`, but one could have also used lazy dot `.*?`.  Your code appears to be using both, sort of.  In this case though, we can just state take any number of digits, because a digit is by definition not a closing brace.

Full code:

```
String input = "{233}{232}{112}{3232}";

if (input.matches("(?:\\{\\d*\\})+")) {
    System.out.println("Match!");
}
```

### Demo

Comment: This does still pass the {xx}{YY} test that he stated should fail, it should also be checking that it is also a digit (?:\{[^}\D]*\})+

Comment: @PraveenRawat My name isn't `Tin`, but appreciate the feedback.

Comment: sorry @TimBiegeleisen for spell mistake